# Save As/Upload or any such new window not Opening

Tags: gui, upload

This is an extension of my previous question. My Ubuntu just doesn't show a new window when it opens. The screen goes darker but I can't see the new window open up. As requested, I got the log at the time and here is what it read:

Apr 5 16:51:59 dell-B85M-DS3H-A gnome-shell[1820]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.

Can someone please help me fix this? Without Save as or Upload Windows working my work has been affected rather severely.

Edit: I finally figured out the problem. My Save as is coming outside my monitor i.e. I see when I click on activities - it lies beside my Browser. But I can't access it. What is the fix to allow a popup to come in front of you instead of beside your current window?

Comment: Please clarify: "a new window"? What window? What triggers this new window? Where did you get the log? Be specific and precise. Remember we are not at your screen.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this myself. Sorry for all the hassle created. The problem disappeared when I made my display single instead of joining two displays. Thank you for all the assistance.